# Why is financial data of some public companies not available on Yahoo Finance?

Tags: stocks, balance-sheet, income-statement, yahoo-finance

On Yahoo! Finance, why isn't the financial data of some companies available? e.g:
[this Canadian company](http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=PRE.TO).

Because if this is a public company, the data must be made public.

Comment: Why are you blaming Yahoo for this ?? Yahoo isn't the original source for all this information, it is the legal body which oversees the firms listed on the stock exchanges in a country(i.e. SEC in US). Then you can browse through the company's web pages to locate any information available and then you come down to yahoo and other sites like yahoo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the short answer is to use SEDAR, the Canadian database that compiles financial statements for Canadian companies. The financial statements for Pacific Rubiales Energy Corp can be found [here](http://www.sedar.com/DisplayProfile.do?lang=EN&issuerType=03&issuerNo=00007953).

The long answer is that the data might be missing because in Canada, each province has their own agency to regulate securities. Yahoo might not compile information from such a wide array of sources. If other countries also have a decentralized system, Yahoo might not take the time to compile financial information from all these sources. There are a myriad of other reasons that could cause this too, however.

This is why [SEDAR](http://www.sedar.com/) is useful; it 's the Canadian equivalent of the SEC's EDGAR database, and it maintains a *sizeable* database of financial statements.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pacificrubiales.com/investor-relations/reports.html does have financial reports on their website for the example you list.  There is the potential for some data to not be easily imported into a format that Yahoo! Finance uses would be my guess for why some data may be missing though an alternative explanation for some companies would be that they may not have been around for a long enough time period to report this information,e.g. if the company is a spin-off of an existing company.